# How to set ping response of AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I hosted one website in AWS. When I try to open in a browser it's working properly. But when I try to ping same website that time it's not sent a response. so how to enable ping response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we created a new instance in aws ec2, by default aws security group block all protocol and port.

AWS security groups block ICMP (including ping, traceroute, etc.) by default. You need to explicitly enable it.

So, enable ICMP protocol (ping response) follow below steps.

Go to **EC2 Dashboard** and click "**Running Instances**"

on **"Security Groups"**, select the group of your instance which you need to add security.

click on the "**Inbound**" tab

Click "**Edit**" Button (It will open a popup window)

click "**Add Rule**"

Select the "**Custom ICMP rule - IPv4**" as Type

Select "**Echo Request**" as the Protocol (Port Range by default show as "N/A)

Enter the "**0.0.0.0/0**" as Source

Click "**Save**"

Comment: In addition to what has been mentioned in the above answer . Here is the official AWS documentation for your reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-ping